# CKEditor5: How to update model when button pressed in balloon?

Tags: ckeditor5

I'm creating a slightly more complicated ["Simple Box" plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/tutorials/widgets/implementing-a-block-widget.html) (which I've renamed to "Callout") where the user can "align" the box floated left, full width, or floated right. I want to present the user alignment buttons in balloon, similar to what you get from the image plugin. Using the buttons should control a CSS class on the outer element.

I've gotten far enough where I have the balloon rendering with the 3 alignment buttons:

[image: Simple Box widget with a title and description with alignment buttons shown]

However, I don't know how to "react" to the buttons being pressed. I have this code for the balloon UI:

```
export default class CalloutBalloonView extends View {
  constructor( locale ) {
    super( locale );

    this.leftAlignView = this._createButton('left', 'Left Align', icons.objectLeft);
    this.fullView = this._createButton('full', 'Full Width', icons.objectFullWidth);
    this.rightAlignView = this._createButton('right', 'Right Align', icons.objectRight);

    this.childViews = this.createCollection( [
      this.leftAlignView,
      this.fullView,
      this.rightAlignView
    ] );

    this.setTemplate( {
      tag: 'div',
      attributes: {
        class: [ 'ck', 'ck-callout-align' ],
        tabindex: '-1'
      },
      children: this.childViews
    });
  }

  focus() {
    this.childViews.first.focus();
  }

  _createButton( name, label, icon) {
    const button = new ButtonView();

    button.set( {
      label,
      icon,
      tooltip: true,
      class: 'testing'
    } );

    return button;
  }
}
```

Here's the main UI code for the plugin:

```
export default class CalloutUI extends Plugin {
  static get requires() {
    return [ ContextualBalloon ];
  }

  init() {
    const editor = this.editor;

    // Create balloon.
    this.balloonView = this._createBalloonView();
    this._balloon = this.editor.plugins.get( ContextualBalloon );

    // This will register the callout toolbar button.
    editor.ui.componentFactory.add('callout', (locale) => {
      const command = editor.commands.get('insertCallout');
      const buttonView = new ButtonView(locale);

      // Create the toolbar button.
      buttonView.set({
        label: editor.t('Callout'),
        icon,
        tooltip: true,
      });

      // Bind the state of the button to the command.
      buttonView.bind('isOn', 'isEnabled').to(command, 'value', 'isEnabled');

      // Execute the command when the button is clicked (executed).
      this.listenTo(buttonView, 'execute', () => {
        editor.execute('insertCallout');
        this._showBalloon()
      });

      return buttonView;
    });
  }
  _getBalloonPositionData() {
    const view = this.editor.editing.view;
    const viewDocument = view.document;
    let target = null;

    // Set a target position by converting view selection range to DOM.
    target = () => view.domConverter.viewRangeToDom(
      viewDocument.selection.getFirstRange()
    );

    return {
      target
    };
  }

  _createBalloonView() {
    const editor = this.editor;
    const balloonView = new CalloutBalloonView( editor.locale );

    this.listenTo( balloonView, 'submit', () => {
      const title = formView.titleInputView.fieldView.element.value;
      const abbr = formView.abbrInputView.fieldView.element.value;
    } );

    return balloonView;
  }

  _showBalloon() {
    this._balloon.add( {
      view: this.balloonView,
      position: this._getBalloonPositionData()
    } );

    //this.balloonView.focus();
  }
}
```

Do I need to listen to the ["isOn" event](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_button_buttonview-ButtonView.html#event-change:isOn) from each buttonView and then manipulate the model somehow to change the "position" attribute on the top level callout? I tried looking at examples from the image plugin provided by CKEditor core, but it's not creating the balloon UI the same way and I'm finding it difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add some listener to your button.

I assume the balloon show when you select your box. You can try using [`Alignment`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/text-alignment.html#common-api) commands to align your selected content.

Call this command in your listener

```js
editor.execute( 'alignment', { value: 'center' } );
```

Here is the [`SupportedOptions`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_alignment_alignmentconfig-SupportedOption.html) for `value`